# Open an image gallery on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So i have a page that has a bunch of product thumbnails and each of them should have a gallery that slides down on a button click. I did that, but the problem is that when i click a button it slides down the gallery's of each product and i dont want that. I know i can do that by adding different id's on the buttons and gallery's but that would require me to copy and paste the code a bunch of times and that's just not good practice. I'm not a jQuery expert and i dont know much about DOM traversal so i need a bit of help with that, just to point me in the right direction.

Here is a pen i made to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmbdXz

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(".product-wrapper #galleryTrigger").on("click", function() {
  $(".gallery").slideToggle();
});
```

As you can see in the pen when you click "Foto" it triggers all the image gallery's on the page. 
I also tried with this code but it didn't work:

```
$(".product-wrapper #galleryTrigger").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".gallery").slideToggle();
});
```

Any advice would help. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings(".gallery").slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply replace `.closest()` in your second attempt with `.next()`:

```
$(".product-wrapper #galleryTrigger").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next(".gallery").slideToggle();
});
```

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this working **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/KmyGex)**.

Note that you also have duplicate IDs for `#galleryTrigger`, which might cause some confusion with the jQuery (in addition to being invalid markup). You may want to substitute with classes.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one works too. :) I just copied and pasted the code to get it done faster, so forgot about the duplicates, thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(this).parent().find(".gallery").slideToggle();
```